# C# Arranging text box in the order of text file

Tags: c#, textbox, text-files, panel, line-breaks

I am reading from textfile and trying to create textbox within the same layout as textfile. But when I tried to code it based on what I know (I am new to this), the textbox gone haywire.
For example in my text file it reads:

> H,E,L,L,O,
>
> E, , , , ,
>
> Y, , , , ,

I want the text box to be created according to the format above, text box will appear where the letters are, then the blanks are just textboxes too but I set their visibility to hidden, however it don't work the work that I thought. Basically I need a 5x5 layout textbox like the text file, and those with letters will have their textbox visible true, those with blank will have their textboxes hidden.

It turn out to be something like this:

[image]

Here is my code that I have tried:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath(@daoWordPuzzle.GetfileURL())))
{
    string line;
    while((line =reader.ReadLine()) !=null)             
    {
        //  Response.Write(line + " <br />"); // Read every line in text file.
        string[] lol = line.Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (var value in lol)
        { 
            int i = 0;
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.MaxLength = (1);
            tb.Width = Unit.Pixel(40);
            tb.Height = Unit.Pixel(40);
            tb.ID = i.ToString();
                     
            // Response.Write(value);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                tb.Style["visibility"] = "hidden";
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                tb.Text = "";
            }
            Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to loop it and if textbox reach 10 I do a line break but that doesn't help
Code here:

```
foreach (var value in lol)
{ 
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.MaxLength = (1);
    tb.Width = Unit.Pixel(40);
    tb.Height = Unit.Pixel(40);
    tb.ID = i.ToString();
                    
    // Response.Write(value);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        tb.Style["visibility"] = "hidden";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        tb.Text = "";
    }
    if (k > 9)
    {
        Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
        k = 0;
    }
    if (k < 9)
    {
        Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
                   
    k++;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: [Scrabble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble)?

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding and setting `.Left` and `.Top` and storing variables,

This is a possible method.

This works, Tested it and it works.

```
int leftStart = 0;
int topStart = 0;

using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\\hello.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //  Response.Write(line + " <br />"); // Read every line in text file.
        string[] lol = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (var value in lol)
        {
            int i = 0;
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.MaxLength = (1);
            tb.Width = 40;
            tb.Height = 40;
            tb.Left = leftStart;
            tb.Top = topStart;
            tb.Visible = true;

            // Response.Write(value);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                //tb.Style["visibility"] = "hidden";
                tb.Visible = false;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                tb.Text = "";
            }

            panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
            i++;
            leftStart = leftStart + 50;
        }
        topStart = topStart + 50;
        leftStart = 0;

    }
}
```

hello.txt contains:

> H,E,L,L,O,
>
> E,,,,,
>
> Y,,,,,

Comment: hi there , thanks for your effort and time , but theres no definition for Left and TopStart , is there any namespace for it?

Comment: I editted the code. Textboxes in C# indeed do use .Left and .Top it is used to position the element on the form.

Comment: I imagine the OPs textboxes might not have left and top if they are System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxes, as hinted at by the OP also adding LiteralControl("<br/>") in his second code block.

Comment: I still showed OP the correct way to do such a task. Why was he doing two for loops? Anyways i'm sure he can figure it out from now, I gave him a huge boost.